# Simplifing MySQL nested SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, nested

```
id    title    slug    summary
------------------------------
1     title1   slug1   summary1
2     title2   slug2   summary2
3     title3   slug3   summary3
4     title4   slug4   summary4
```

I'm trying to select all fields, and in the meanwhile, select id, title and slug of prev/next row

```
SELECT
    title, slug, summary, id as current_id,
    (SELECT id    FROM table WHERE id < current_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev_id,
    (SELECT title FROM table WHERE id < current_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev_title,
    (SELECT slug  FROM table WHERE id < current_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev_slug,
    /*
    (SELECT id ...  ) AS next_id
    (SELECT title...) AS next_title
    ...
    and if there are more fields to select, I have to repeat this (SELECT...)
    */
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id IN (2,3,4);
```

The query works but apparently it's not the smart way to do so.

Can some please help with simplifing this? Thanks

Comment: There is a better way in SQL - just not with the limited SQL features MySQL has.

Comment: we are eager to learn from you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I thought this would be easy. But after an hour without a working solution, I'm gonna answer my own question with the way I just figured out.

using **CONCAT_WS**

```
SELECT
    title, slug, summary, id as current_id,
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT_WS(',' id, title, slug)
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            id < current_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    ) AS prev_data,
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT_WS(',' id, title, slug)
        FROM
            table
        WHERE
            id > current_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
    ) AS next_data
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id IN (2,3,4);
```

and the result would be something like

```
id        => 2
title     => title2
slug      => slug2
summary   => summary2
prev_data => 1,title1,slug1
next_data => 3,title3,slug3
```

then I have to `explode`(PHP) `prev_data` and `next_data` to get details.

I'm still looking for a (better) way to do this with MySQL only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **the `Id` column is `auto_increment`** and the values **do not have gaps between `id`'s** (meaning they are incremented as 1, 2, 3, 4. No gaps in between like 1, 3, 4, 6), then you can try this one:

```
SELECT T.Id AS CurrentId
    , T.Title AS CurrentTitle
    , T.Slug AS CurrentSlug
    , T.Summary AS CurrentSummary
    , IFNULL(P.Id, -1) AS PreviousId
    , IFNULL(P.Title, '') AS PreviousTitle
    , IFNULL(P.Slug, '') AS PreviousSlug
    , IFNULL(P.Summary, '') AS PreviousSummary
    , IFNULL(N.Id, -1) AS NextId
    , IFNULL(N.Title, '') AS NextTitle
    , IFNULL(N.Slug, '') AS NextSlug
    , IFNULL(N.Summary, '') AS NextSummary
    FROM table T
    LEFT JOIN table P ON P.Id - 1 = T.Id
    LEFT JOIN table N ON N.Id + 1 = T.Id
    WHERE T.Id IN (2, 3, 4);
```

Otherwise, the answer you've posted is correct.

Comment: Thanks Kael. the id column _is_ auto_increment, but it cannot be guaranteed with no gaps since entries are deleted from time to time. that's why I have to use > and <.

Comment: I see. Just an idea, if you happen to use any server side language [`C#`, `Java`, etc.], maybe you can try to get the `previous` and `next` record in the code, not in the query. Just thinking of balancing the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the columns from one subquery:

```
SELECT
    title, slug, summary, id as current_id, prev.prev_id, prev.prev_title, prev.prev_slug, next.next_id, next.next_title, next.next_slug
FROM
    table,
    (SELECT id AS prev_id, title AS prev_title, slug AS prev_slug FROM table WHERE id < 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev,
    (SELECT id AS next_id, title AS next_title, slug AS next_slug FROM table WHERE id > 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS next
WHERE
    id = 2;
```

But this wouldn't work if you have to use an `IN` clause in your where; you would need to run this query for each value of `id`...

Comment: too bad I'm fetching multiple rows at one time... I thought this would be easy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work. I didn't test it so I'm not sure, but looks good :)

```
SELECT
  current.title as current_title,
  current.slug as current_slug,
  current.summary as current_summary, 
  current.id as current_id,
  prev.title as prev_title,
  prev.slug as prev_slug,
  prev.summary as prev_summary,
  prev.id as prev_id,
  next.title as next_title,
  next.slug as next_slug,
  next.summary as next_summary,
  nexrt.id as next_id
FROM
  `table` current LEFT JOIN 
  `table` prev ON prev.id = current.id - 1 LEFT JOIN
  `table` next ON next.id = current.id + 1                    
WHERE
  current.id IN (2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necromancing a 6 yo question, but have to do so :)
`LAG()` and `LEAD()` to the rescue!
Pretty handy, available in Oracle and SQL Server too:

```
select 
    title, lead (title) over (order by id) next_title, lag (title) over (order by id) prev_title,
    slug, lead (slug) over (order by id) next_slug, lag (slug) over (order by id) prev_slug,
    summary, lead (summary) over (order by id) next_summary, lag (summary) over (order by id) prev_summary,
    id, lead (id) over (order by id) next_id, lag (id) over (order by id) prev_id
from `table`
;
/*
create table `table` as
(select id, concat('title', id) title, concat('slug', id) slug, concat('summary', id) summary
from
(select 1 id union all
select 14 id union all
select 34 id union all
select 13 id union all
select 2 id union all
select 4 id ) as q)
*/
```